# Error while navigating on button click in Angular 2

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to use navigateurl property on button click but seems like it is broken. I am getting below error:

```
:53806/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1389 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'component' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'component' of null
    at PreActivation.setupRouteGuards (:53806/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:3601)
    at eval (:53806/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:3550)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at PreActivation.setupChildRouteGuards (:53806/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:3549)
    at PreActivation.initialize (:53806/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:3483)
    at MapSubscriber.eval [as project] (:53806/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:5311)
    at MapSubscriber._next (:53806/node_modules/rxjs/operators/map.js:79)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (:53806/node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:89)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (:53806/node_modules/rxjs/operators/mergeMap.js:145)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (:53806/node_modules/rxjs/InnerSubscriber.js:23)
    at PreActivation.setupRouteGuards (:53806/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:3601)
    at eval (:53806/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:3550)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at PreActivation.setupChildRouteGuards (:53806/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:3549)
    at PreActivation.initialize (:53806/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:3483)
    at MapSubscriber.eval [as project] (:53806/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:5311)
    at MapSubscriber._next (:53806/node_modules/rxjs/operators/map.js:79)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (:53806/node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:89)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (:53806/node_modules/rxjs/operators/mergeMap.js:145)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (:53806/node_modules/rxjs/InnerSubscriber.js:23)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:824)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:795)
    at zone.js:873
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (:53806/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:4659)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:602)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:503)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1540)
defaultErrorLogger @ :53806/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1389
```

My typescript file code is: -

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: 'src/app/dashboard/app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent {
    name: string = 'Angular';

    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    btnClick() {
        console.log("Button has been clicked");
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/exportPdf');
    };
}
```

And the page where i want to redirect, typescript code is: -

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'


@Component({
    selector: 'exportPdf',
    templateUrl: 'src/app/exportPdf/exportPdf.component.html'
})


export class ExportPdfComponent { name: string = "Export View to Pdf" }
```

Module.ts file: -

Here is my module.ts code

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './dashboard/app.component';
import { ExportPdfComponent } from './exportPdf/exportPdf.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'Dashboard', component: AppComponent },
    { path: 'ExportPdf', component: ExportPdfComponent }
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
    declarations: [AppComponent, ExportPdfComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent, ExportPdfComponent]
})

export class AppModule {
}
```

If you guys have faced this kind of error before then please let me know how did you resolved that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show your routes module ?

Comment: templateUrl: './exportPdf.component.html'

Comment: @MohamedAliRACHID updated.

Comment: @DmitryGrinko i have tried that but did not work.

Comment: Are you sure your dashboard directory includes the app.component? Actually It is very strange import { AppComponent } from './dashboard/app.component';

Comment: @DmitryGrinko yes it includes the app.component at parent level of the directory.

Answer (score 1):

If currently no router-outlet is present (for example it will be removed from content because of some other errors) and pre activation rules are set (such as AuthGuard) the routing will fail with something like:

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'component' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'component' of null
    at PreActivation.webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.PreActivation.traverseRoutes (router.es5.js:4346)
    at router.es5.js:4308
    at Array.forEach ()
    at PreActivation.webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.PreActivation.traverseChildRoutes (router.es5.js:4307)
    at PreActivation.webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.PreActivation.traverseRoutes (router.es5.js:4338)
[..]

Please check the same to resolve your issue.

Comment: I was hiding my router-outlet upon error. Moving the router-outlet outside the hidden template fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be much more helpful if you could show us your **route configuration** as well as your **route guard**. Typically, route config can be found in `app.module.ts` file, with code similar to this

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'exportPdf', component: ExportPdfComponent },
  ...
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`PreActivation.setupRouteGuards` may also suggest there might be issue with your route guard. So you might want to double check route config and guard and debug the code if necessary.

Comment: Update please check

Comment: @Sagar `bootstrap: [AppComponent, ExportPdfComponent]` not sure why you added ExportPdfComponent there. Normally, we bootstrap `AppComponent` only

Answer (score 0):

### USE routerLink attribute

```
<button type="button" mat-raised-button color="warn" routerLink="/route">
```